# Is it possible to use Millis() function to calculate total time taken?

Tags: esp8266

I have two conditional statement ,
for example ,

if(x<1&&y>6)

{

//get the total time(second) inside this conditional statement

}

if(x<20&&y>30)

{

//get the total time(second) inside this conditional statement

}

My question is,

is it possible use Millis () function to calculate the total time in each "if condition"??

or any other method to calculate time?

please  give me some code examples.

Thanks

Comment: Realistically, miliseconds won't tell you very much for such a small code fragment. Modern processors (anything post moon landings) are much faster than that. There are faster clocks but simply putting the function call in to read the clock will take proportionally significant time. The traditional approach is to call the code perhaps 1000 times - enough times that you can physically see the delay, measure the total duration and divide down.

Comment: @GemTaylor please give me some code examples.

Answer (score 0):

I have did it according to my understanding if there is something else you were trying to do tell me i will change it accordingly.

```
uint32_t sec1, sec2;


uint32_t sec = millis()/1000;
if(x<1&&y>6) {
//get the total time(second) inside this conditional statement

//Adding time for summing up the seconds
sec1 = sec1 + (millis() / 1000) - sec;
}

if(x<20&&y>30) {

//get the total time(second) inside this conditional statement

//Adding time for summing up the seconds
sec2 = sec2 + (millis() / 1000) - sec;
}
```